# MongoDB create a new collection from the client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**Intro**:

I have a collection of players in my app, this is built using a schema and then passing some stuff into my node.js configuration, perhaps it's a bit more complex than that but I mean this is the basic idea of how mongoDB for nodejs works with models and collections.

So now in my database I have my DB name then collections then a collection of players, great now I can build an api and start making requests to GET and PUT from that collection.

---

**Question**:

My problem is in my stats app after week one's game was tracked I need to clear all the player attributes so that in week 2 it's fresh, but I would like to save all the stats for the players from week 1.

So due to my basic knowledge of how a collection is built I am thinking in order to build a new collection I need to define a schema, but perhaps there is another way, if not then the schema would have to be dynamic right? Well how do I build a dynamic schema to suit this problem?

---

**Ideas**:

- **Idea**: The user clicks a button saying complete week 1, then the server takes all the data from the players collection and builds a
  new collection named week 1 players?

  **Question:** If the above is a good idea, how do I build a function to create a new mongoDB collection and save players_week1 into its
  own branch?

---

**Final Word**:

So hopefully someone has an optimal solution and understands what I am talking about, in the mean time I am going to try and follow my idea and see if I can search the docs to find some answers. Thanks guys.

Comment: Maybe you could store all the attributes that will change week to week in a separate collection that would reference the players collection. Otherwise, the function you need to create a new collection is db.createCollection().

Comment: Yeah after a quick google search I came across that, I am still trying to think of a way to build the function. I need to read more about it but I guess the user client side can trigger a function that runs db.createCollection(); and store the current models there then clear the current models? something like that I am playing around with it.

Comment: The one problem I am having with that is I am using mongoose, and I am not sure if I can use `db` in my app I just directly use the model. Does that make sense? I have not used `db` one time, I hope that is available.

Comment: Yeah `db` is not defined.

Comment: You could also scope the call to get the players stats to just the week you want to look at. Something like PlayerStats
                        .find()
                        .where( { 'timestamp': weekOne})

Comment: Yeah I like that idea and considered it but when week 2 hits I need clear data.

Comment: 'db' should be the name of you model. They just use 'db' because everyones models will be named differently.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for? http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/

Comment: Oh doh, lol. Okay I think I made the same mistake before, ill try Players.createCollection()

Comment: Okay copyTo looks good thanks man. I got a lot of playing around to do, I think I get the gist!